# Weird apache2 alias error

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin, alias

I'm running apache2 on turnkey linux and i apt-get installed mysql and phpmyadmin, everything works fine with my alias ip/phpmyadmin2, ip/phpmyadmin gives an error page about php, but when i set the alias to ip/phpmyadmin it gives the same error just like it ignored my alias and ip/phpmyadmin2 still works although I removed that alias. I checked every config and there seems that there isn't any alias conflicts. Is there a alias log file that I should know about?

Comment: Did you restart Apache or reload its configuration? Aliases are at the virtualhost or server level, and any changes require a restart or reload.

Comment: I did, I even restarted the whole machine. I left it on over night and now somehow it works?! WTF?!

Comment: The time delay suggests you might have seen browser caching behavior.

Comment: Hmm maybe, well It works now, thanks for the advice anyway :)